# Перевод int в сhar C++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть вот такой код:

```
void Encode(char encode[]){
int ready;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(encode);i++){
    ready=(int)encode[i];
    cout<<ready<<'#';
}
```

Мы вводим строку, программа переводит каждый символ в int 
и разделяет их с помощью '#'

- Например: вводим abc
- Получаем: 97#98#99#

Нужно сделать обратную функцию, тобишь

- вводим: 97#98#99#
- получаем: abc

Comment: И в чем состоит проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void Decode( int* code, int size ){
    for( int i( 0 ); i < size; ++i )
        std::cout << static_cast<char>( code[ i ] ) <<'#';
}
void Decode( const std::string& string ){
    std::string number;
    int d;
    for( int i( 0 ); i < string.size(); ++i ){
        if( string[ i ] == '#' ){
            std::istringstream( number ) >> d;
            std::cout << static_cast<char>( d );
            number.clear();
        }else number += string[ i ];
    }
}

int main(){ 
    //int arr[ 3 ] = { 97, 98, 99 };
    //Decode( arr, 3 );
    std::string string( "97#98#99#" );
    Decode( string );
    return 0;
}
```